# How to get xpath contain both text in 2 line break

Tags: javascript, selenium, ui-automation

I have a content like this
[image]

How can I get that xpath to assert in one for both **The email field is required.** and **The Password field is required.**

thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

The simplest XPath to assert both these texts is:

```
"//*[contains(.,'The Email field is required')][contains(.,'The Password field is required')]"
```

You can make it more precise by specifying the tag name `div`

```
"//div[contains(.,'The Email field is required')][contains(.,'The Password field is required')]"
```